# Preserve Encapsulation while Displaying Information

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

Suppose I've got the following class to represent a `Car` and `Tire`:

```
public final class Tire{

    private final String brand
    private final TireType type;

    public Tire(String brand, type)
    {
      this.brand = brand
      this.type = type;      
    }

    //getters and toString() for tire attributes
}


public final class Car{

    private final String name;
    private final Tire tire;

    public Car(String name, Tire tire){
        this.name = name;
        this.tire = tire;     
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;   
    } 
}
```

I'm fully aware that my `Car` and `Tire` example are lacking notable attributes, but that's not the focus of my question, it's the simplest [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I could come up with.

From Effective Java(p. 53):

> Whether or not you specify the format, provide programmatic access to
>   all of the information contained in the value returned by `toString`.

In my `Car` class, the `toString()` method will obviously return the name, and according to Effective Java, as quoted above I should provide a `getter` as well. My problem is when returning the details of the Tire.

**Question:**

Given the advice quoted from Effective Java, how would I properly return the details of my car including the Tire for display purposes?

Would I do this:

```
public Tire getTire(){
    return this.tire   
}

public String toString(){
     return  "Name:  " + this.name + " Tire: " + this.tire;   
}
```

Or to put it another way, when you have a class, in my case(`Tire`), that is also an attribute of another class, in my case(`Car`), when returning the details to be printed in a GUI, how would I do so and perverse encapsulation?

Comment: Override `toString()` in `Tire`?

Comment: @JimGarrison - That's what the comment in `Tire` states, I did, but left it out of the example. It would make it too long. My real question is, is providing a getter for `Tire` in `Car` breaking encapsulation?

Comment: What do you mean with `public final String Tire tire; ` in Car class?

Comment: @HJuls2 - Mistake, sorry

Comment: Wanna encapsulation? - Hide all fields/getters and provide method `String print()`. Why not `ToString`? - Suppose you wanna extend this object and return some text  and image.... how would you  change than `ToString` signature? It's handy for debug, but not for using as part of logic.

Comment: But your `String print()` does the same, it returns a `string`, I don't see how you can return an image from a method that returns a `string`

Comment: @S.R., yes, it's does same, but it's mine. `ToString` is part of `Object` and we doesn't control it. But never mind, it's just matter of design.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
public class Tire
{
    private string m_brand;
    private string m_type;
    public Tire(string brand, string type)
    {
        this.m_brand = brand;
        this.m_type = type;
    }

    public string getTireBrand()
    {
        return this.m_brand;
    }

    public string getTireType()
    {
        return this.m_type;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "brand - " + this.m_brand + ", type - " + this.m_type;
    }
}

public class Car
{
    private string m_name;
    private Tire m_tire;

    public Car(string name, Tire tire)
    {
        this.m_name = name;
        this.m_tire = tire;
    }

    public string getCarDetails()
    {
        string car = this.m_name;
        string tireBrand = this.m_tire.getTireBrand();
        string tireType = this.m_tire.getTireType();

        return "Name:  " + car + " Tire: brand - " + tireBrand + ", type - " + tireType;
    }

    public string _getCarDetails()
    {
        return "Name:  " + this.m_name + " Tire: " + this.m_tire.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From book:

> Whether or not you specify the format, provide programmatic access to all of the information contained in the value returned by toString
>   ***If you fail to do this, you force programmers who need this information to parse the string.***

If you use some really really private information in `ToString`, than there is a chance that someone will extract it. I would say it differently: use only public information in toString ***or*** use toString only for debugging, not for implementation logic.

Answer (score 0):

This conflict (and it is a conflict, you can't have both!) can be solved by deciding what you value more. Do you value OO, Encapsulation, Law of Demeter more than that quoted advice from Effective Java.

If you value the former, then the advice from Effective Java can't be really followed. I would even argue that having *any* getters is wrong inside an application (a library with a public API is somewhat different).

If you value the advice more, then obviously you can define whatever getters you want.

I know this isn't a satisfying answer, but don't be fooled that you can have both! You can't.